# HTML5 audio from mongodb GridFS

Tags: html, mongodb, audio, gridfs

I have a MongoDB database with audio files stored in GridFS. HTML5 audio tag works with a link to a method that gets audio from MongoDB:

```
$file = $grid->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));
header('Content-Length: ' . $file->file['length']);
header('Content-Type: ' . $file->file['file_type']);
header("Content-Disposition: filename=" . $file->file['filename']);
echo $file->getBytes();
```

All is good but one thing: I can't use slidebar to skip through audio, it only plays from start to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `Accept-Ranges = bytes` header.  From http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/:

> Most audio-capable browsers enable seeking to new file positions
>   during a download. To allow this, you must enable range requests on
>   your server. Although enabled by default on web servers such as
>   Apache, you can verify by checking that your server responds with the
>   Accept-Ranges header.

Also a [`X-Content-Duration = length_in_seconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) header may help if the files are in ogg format.  From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media:

> The Ogg format doesn't encapsulate the duration of media, so for the
>   progress bar on the video controls to display the duration of the
>   video, Gecko needs to determine the length of the media using other
>   means.
>
> There are two ways Gecko can do this. The best way is to offer an
>   X-Content-Duration header when serving Ogg media files. This header
>   provides the duration of the video in seconds (not in HH:MM:SS format)
>   as a floating-point value.

Both of these headers help the browser to determine the audio's duration before the file is fully downloaded so that seeking is possible, and the playhead can be positioned properly.

Comment: Thank you,  
"Accept-Ranges: bytes" fixed the problem.

Comment: I would still suggest to improve your PHP script to support ranges as well. Also, instead of getBytes I suggest you use getResource and use PHP's stream functionality. It will save you lots of memory.

Comment: Good tip, wasn't following mongo development as of lately but updated my mongo instance and now I use  
`$stream = $file->getResource();                        
 while (!feof($stream)) {
     echo fread($stream, 8192);
 }`  
I don't know how much of a performance boost I got but it's always good to learn new things.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do scrolling, I expect that your script needs to handle ranges as well. Could also supply your (sample) HTML page? Then I can experiment a little bit to see if I can come up with a better answer.

Comment: I'm doing this in local network, so I can't link to it but my html output looks like:  
`<audio id="audio" controls="controls" preload="auto">
<source src="<?php echo site_url() . "records/getAudio/" . $i->file['_id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $i->file['file_type']; ?>" />
Use Google Chrome.
</audio>`  

I don't use any scripts except setting volume to 0.1:
`audio=document.getElementById("audio");
audio.volume = 0.1;
`